# Solidity version 8 Error: msg.value

Tags: solidity-0.8.x

I am trying to compile a smart contract written in version 8 Solidity:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.10;
contract T {
   address payable k;
   uint public cP = 100;
   address payable owner;
   constructor() {
      owner =  payable (msg.sender); 
   }
   function sC(uint val) public payable{
      owner.transfer(val);
   }
   receive() external payable {
      if (msg.value < cP) revert;
      int c= 100;
      k.send(c);
   }
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: No matching declaration found after variable lookup.
--> remix2.sol:17:22:
|
17 | if (msg.value < cP) revert;
| ^^^^^^
```

Somebody please guide me.
Zulfi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

revert is a function statement

```
receive() external payable {
  if (msg.value < cP) revert();
  uint c= 100;
  k.send(c);
```

}